# In GTK+3, how do I get a drawingarea to respond to mouse events?

Tags: c, mouseevent, gtk3, drawingarea

In GTK+3, how do I get a drawing_area to respond to mouse events?

In ***main()*** function I declared my ***drawing_area***:

```
GtkWidget *drawing_area;
```

Then I connected the ***drawing_area*** with the mouse click signal:

```
g_signal_connect(drawing_area, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);
```

the function "clicked" is defined by:

```
static gboolean clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer user_data)

    printf("Clicked! \n");

    return TRUE;
}
```

The program runs and shows the drawing_area but when I click on it, no answer, nothing happens! Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that GtkDrawingArea can not receive mouse events by default

Take a look to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html#GtkDrawingArea.implemented-interfaces):

> To receive mouse events on a drawing area, you will need to enable
>   them with gtk_widget_add_events(). To receive keyboard events, you
>   will need to set the “can-focus” property on the drawing area, and you
>   should probably draw some user-visible indication that the drawing
>   area is focused. Use gtk_widget_has_focus() in your expose event
>   handler to decide whether to draw the focus indicator. See
>   gtk_render_focus() for one way to draw focus.

Or try connecting the event `"button-press-event"` to the window:

```
g_signal_connect(window, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);
```

instead of

```
g_signal_connect(drawing_area, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);
```

As in this example:

http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/basicdrawing/

Comment: That works but not very well because I have my drawing area embedded inside a GUI, so wherever I click in the GUI window (even if it is outside the drawing area) the click event is processed. I just want the mouse event to be processed only when I click in the drawing area and nowhere else!

Comment: thanks, it works now. I added  **gtk_widget_add_events(drawing_area, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);**

Answer (score 1):

A complete example is:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s05.html
This link has moved (thanks TrentP). The new link is:
https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html#custom-drawing

It demonstrates input event handling by means of ::button-press and ::motion-notify handlers.

Comment: To add mouse click and mouse motion events: gtk_widget_set_events(drawing_area,gtk_widget_get_events(drawing_area) | GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK   | GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK);

Comment: The example appears to now be at https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html#custom-drawing

Comment: Thank you. After GTK4 the links are revised. I am editing the original answer.